# Listview with Search and DataPager controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datapager

As this is my first project, I really do not have much idea to debug this. I have a listview. I am writing code manually to populate listview. As the listview is very large, I have a search button where user enters a search string. I am trying to build a sql string from here and populate the listview. Everything works fine but when I click on next page, it does not include the search string. I think it is just populating the 2nd page without the search criteria. If I remove the data pager control, it works fine. I am not able to put proper code datapger_PagePropertiesChanging. I appreciate if  someone can help me with this.

Here is my list view markup:

```
         <asp:ListView ID="lvContractors" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvContractors_PagePropertiesChanging">
           <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="ListViewGrid">
                <table class="tblpadding">
                  <tr>
                      <th class="HeaderStyle">
                           Contractor Number
                      </th>
                      <th class="HeaderStyle">
                           First Name
                      </th>
                      <th class="HeaderStyle">
                           Last Name
                      </th>
                      <th class="HeaderStyle">
                           View
                      </th>
                      <th class="HeaderStyle">
                           Edit
                      </th>
                   </tr>
                   <tbody><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" /></tbody>

                 </table>
             </div> <!-- End of ListViewGrid -->

             </LayoutTemplate>
             <ItemSeparatorTemplate> <td>   <hr /> </td>

             </ItemSeparatorTemplate>

              <ItemTemplate>
                <div >
                    <tr>
                       <td class="RowStyle"><%#Eval("ContractorNumber")%></td>
                       <td class="RowStyle"><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                       <td class="RowStyle"><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>

                       <td class="RowStyle">
                           <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" runat="server" CssClass="link"
                                NavigateUrl='<%# "ContractorEdit.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ContractorNumber") + "&Mode=" + "CV" %>'
                                Target="_blank" Text="View" />
                       </td>
                       <td class="RowStyle">
                          <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CssClass="link"
                                NavigateUrl= '<%# "ContractorEdit.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ContractorNumber") + "&Mode=" + "CE" %>'
                                Text="Edit"> </asp:HyperLink>

                     </tr>
                  </div>
               </ItemTemplate>
               <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                 <div>
                    <tr>
                       <td class="AlternatingRowStyle"><%#Eval("ContractorNumber")%></td>
                       <td class="AlternatingRowStyle"><%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                       <td class="AlternatingRowStyle"><%#Eval("LastName")%></td>

                       <td class="AlternatingRowStyle">
                           <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" runat="server" CssClass="link"
                                NavigateUrl='<%# "Contractor.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ContractorNumber")%>'
                                Target="_blank" Text="View" />
                       </td>
                       <td class="AlternatingRowStyle">
                          <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CssClass="link"
                                NavigateUrl= '<%# "ContractorEdit.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ContractorNumber") + "&Mode=" + "CE" %>'
                                Text="Edit"> </asp:HyperLink>

                     </tr>
                  </div>

               </AlternatingItemTemplate>

               <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                   <tr>
                      <td colspan="5" class="itemseparator"></td>
                  </tr>
              </ItemSeparatorTemplate>

     </asp:ListView>

     <div class="pager">
        <asp:DataPager PageSize="20" ID="DataPagerContractor" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvContractors"
                        NextPreviousButtonCssClass="PrevNext"
                        CurrentPageLabelCssClass="CurrentPage"
                        NumericButtonCssClass="PageNumber">
            <fields>
                 <asp:NumericPagerField
                      PreviousPageText="&lt; Prev"
                      NextPageText="Next &gt;"
                      ButtonCount="10"
                      NextPreviousButtonCssClass="PrevNext"
                      CurrentPageLabelCssClass="CurrentPage"
                      NumericButtonCssClass="PageNumber" />
            </fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
      </div>
</div> Code behind this: Partial Class Contractor
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private txtKeywordSearchWhereClause As String = ""

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Session("Clicked") = "Contractor"
    End If

    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(txtKeywordSearchWhereClause) Then
        LoadContractors(txtKeywordSearchWhereClause)
    Else
        LoadContractors("")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub LoadContractors(ByVal strSearch As String)
    Dim strConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn").ConnectionString)

    strConn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblContractor1"

    If Not strSearch = "" Then
        sql = sql & strSearch
        sql = sql & " ORDER BY LastName"
    End If


    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, strConn)

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    da.Fill(dt)

    lvContractors.DataSource = dt

    lvContractors.DataBind()
End Sub



Protected Sub buttonAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonAdd.Click
    Response.Redirect("ContractorEdit.aspx", False)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    '   Keyword Search

    Dim txtKeywordSearch As String = txtSearch.Text


    Dim txtWhereClause As String = ""

    If txtKeywordSearch.Trim() <> "" Then
        txtWhereClause = " WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" + txtKeywordSearch + "%'"
        txtWhereClause = txtWhereClause + " OR LastName LIKE '%" + txtKeywordSearch + "%'"
        txtWhereClause = txtWhereClause + " OR ContractorNumber LIKE '%" + txtKeywordSearch + "%'"

        txtKeywordSearchWhereClause = txtWhereClause
    End If

    LoadContractors(txtKeywordSearchWhereClause)

End Sub

Protected Sub lvContractors_PagePropertiesChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs) Handles lvContractors.PagePropertiesChanging
    DataPagerContractor.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    'rebind List View
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(txtKeywordSearchWhereClause) Then
        LoadContractors(txtKeywordSearchWhereClause)
    Else
        LoadContractors("")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: If you store your txtKeywordsearch in session also (and retrive it from there as well) you're pager will work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but this is not possible with the datapager (at least in ASP.Net 3.5). 
The only solution is to write your own pager from scratch as the only querystring parameter the datapager can pass is the page number.